# code push react native not changed library updates on users App

Tags: react-native, code-push

When I changed a library (like 'react-native-image-crop-picker') version on package.json and distribute it with code push in users app the version not changed.
They see older version of that library in app.

what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code Push only works with JS code. It doesn't allow to push native binaries. In your case, you have to update app bundles in stores to update your native dependencies.

> The CodePush plugin helps get product improvements in front of your end users instantly, by keeping your JavaScript and images synchronized with updates you release to the CodePush server.

Taken from [Code Push docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#how-does-it-work).

Comment: But when I add the library code push work completely. What's the difference between Updated library and new library?

Comment: @Mahdi in your case Code Push will only use an updated JS bundle. However, if your dependency (react-native-image-crop-picker) changed a native code, your updated app won't use new binaries.